# My cells are not appearing in my tableView

Tags: swift, xcode

My application worked as expected a few minutes back but I pressed "Undo" a lot to see how I wrote something that I had deleted, I then pressed "Redo" Until all my new code was back but the custom cells in my tableView are not appearing in the app. All I see is an empty tableView.

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelHole: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var labelShots: UILabel!
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var holesTableView: UITableView!


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return mainShotsEachHole.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = holesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

        cell.labelHole?.text = "Hole \(mainCurrentHoleNumber)"

        cell.labelShots?.text = "\(mainShotsEachHole[indexPath.row])"

        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        holesTableView.register(MyTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        holesTableView.delegate = self
        holesTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help you might have. I have been trying to figure this out for an hour now and I can't seem to get this to work.

***Edit - Adding code for ViewController.swift which provides some data.

```
import UIKit

var mainCounterValue = 0
var mainCurrentHoleNumber = 1
var mainShotsEachHole = [Int]()


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func unwindToViewController (segue: UIStoryboardSegue){

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var mainCounter: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var mainHoleNumber: UILabel!

    @IBAction func mainButtonNextHole(_ sender: Any) {
        mainShotsEachHole.append(mainCounterValue)
        mainCurrentHoleNumber += 1
        mainHoleNumber.text = "Hole \(mainCurrentHoleNumber)"
        mainCounterValue = 0
        mainCounter.text = "\(mainCounterValue)"
    }


    @IBAction func mainButtonMinus(_ sender: Any) {
        if (mainCounterValue > 0) {
            mainCounterValue -= 1
        } else {
            mainCounterValue = 0
        }
        mainCounter.text = "\(mainCounterValue)"
    }

    @IBAction func mainButtonPlus(_ sender: Any) {
        mainCounterValue += 1
        mainCounter.text = "\(mainCounterValue)"
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: How are you populating `mainShotsEachHole` and `mainCurrentHoleNumber`? I can't see anywhere there you are filling these variables with any data.

Comment: In my main ViewController.swift
mainShotsEachHole is just plus and minus buttons that changes the a number.
mainCurrentHoleNumber goes up +1 each time you finish one "mainShotsEachHole", so basically a counter of how many times you press "done"

Comment: Provide the whole code of your `ViewController.swift`

Comment: Added to main post.

Comment: My main idea is to add the names of the holes on the left of the cell ("Hole 1", "Hole 2" etc.) and your total shots on the right (5, 4, 2, 1). If you know a simpler way of executing that I would love to know :)

Comment: So, `ViewController` and `SecondViewController` are two different classes right? How are you navigating from `ViewController` to `SecondViewController` and passing value of `mainShotsEachHole` and `mainCurrentHoleNumber` to `SecondViewController`? Your Second view controller doesn't know anything about these variables

Comment: Does this problem still exists? Are you using a storyboard and connect your custom cell outlets to your MyTableViewCell class?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `holesTableView.reloadData()` to fill your table

Comment: Now I can see the cells but they are completely white and empty

Comment: breakpoint this line `cell.labelHole?.text = "Hole \(mainCurrentHoleNumber)"` and check if `cell.labelHole != null`

Comment: No, no. Don't put any condition, just the breakpoint. Run the application, it should stop the execution when the code is passing through the bp. When the execution has stopped there, type on the console `p cell.labelHole`. It will print the labelHole value. I want to know if it is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

holesTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "nibName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

try this above code, hope its help you.